Integral with a constraint on a parameter
I want to evaluate the following integral
$$\int_{c}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-2}(x-a-1)}{(x-a)^2+a} dx,  \qquad a<-1$$
where $c>0$ is a positive constant. When I use the Mathematica with the assumption that $a<-1$, i.e. a command like this
Assuming[a < -1, Integrate[x^(-2)*(x - a - 1)/((x - a)^2 + a), x]]

I get the answer
$$ \frac{\sqrt{a} \left(s \log \left((a-s)^2+a\right)+2 a-2 s \log (-s)+2\right)-2 s \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a-s}{\sqrt{a}}\right)}{2 a^{3/2} (a+1) s} $$
However as is evident from the solution, there is the constant $\sqrt{a}$ in the solution. This makes the solution complex, not a real one. Is there a real solution possible?
Thank you!

How do you know this solution is not real? It is perfectly fine for a real valued function to be defined with complex coefficients.

Thanks for the remark, the left term is okay, the right term is the problem! $\frac{2 s \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a-s}{\sqrt{a}}\right)}{2 a^{3/2} (a+1) s}$, there is $\sqrt{a}$ inside $\tan ^{-1}$ which does not simplify! When $s$ gets different values, this term becomes complex!

I don't think it can be. What's inside ArcTan has real part being 0.

Hmmm, actually, now I understood what you meant! But, can one prove that this equation always gives a real answer? In other words, is the $\tan^{-1}$ of a pure complex number, a pure complex number?

Write Trig functions in terms of Exponentials, $\tan^{-1}(i x)=-(1/2) i (\log(1 - x) - \log(1 + x))$. I think you need $x$ to be in the correct range.

Yes, indeed you are right! If $w = \tan^{-1}(z)$ then $w = \frac{1}{2i}\log \left( \frac{1+iz}{1-iz} \right)$, assuming $z$ is pure imaginary, then $w$ will also be pure imaginary! That means the $i$ in numerator and denominator cancel out and the answer will be real!!!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

There is still one problem left though! What happens at $x \to \infty$? Can we calculate the limit?

Note that Mathematica gives the same result regardless of the inclusion of Assuming (or Integrate's Assumptions option). It can do the limit too:Limit[..., x -> Infinity, Assumptions -> a<-1]

Have you tried $\int_{c}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-2}(x+b^2-1)}{(x+b^2)^2-b^2} dx$?
